# How to suppress indentation in mdframed titles

Tags: babel, mdframed

Consider the following latex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{defstyle}{%
linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,%
frametitlerule=true,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
}
\mdtheorem[style=defstyle]{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
An infinite set $A$ is countable if there exists a bijection $f$ from the 
natural numbers into $A$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Because of the line:

```
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
```

there is a default indentation for paragraphs (that I would like to keep). But this indentation also moves to the right the title of the mdframed box created by the \mdtheorem command. Is there a way to keep a positive default indentation for paragraphs, but to have a normal alignment for mdframed's boxtitles ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{defstyle}{%
linecolor=red, linewidth=2pt,%
frametitlerule=true,%
frametitlebackgroundcolor=gray!20,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
frametitlealignment =\raggedright\noindent
}
\mdtheorem[style=defstyle]{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
An infinite set $A$ is countable if there exists a bijection $f$ from the
natural numbers into $A$.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]